regex to match at certain string and not followed by another string using notepad++
for following sample sql:
CREATE TABLE "abc01"."SLI_EDF_INSTR" 
   (    "EDF_INSTR_KEY" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EDF_KEY" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INSTR_KEY" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_REC_TXN_USER_ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_REC_TXN_TYPE_CODE" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_REC_TXN_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_REC_TXN_USER_POST_NAME" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE);

   

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "abc01"."TRG_SLEI_BIU" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SLI_EDF_INSTR
    FOR EACH ROW
        DECLARE
            post_name VARCHAR2(32);
        BEGIN
            IF :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_USER_ID IS NULL THEN
                :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_USER_ID := 'SYSTEM';
            END IF;

            IF :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_DATE IS NULL OR UPDATING THEN
                :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_DATE := SYSTIMESTAMP;
            END IF;

            IF :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_USER_POST_NAME IS NULL THEN
                SELECT NVL(MAX(USER_POST_NAME), 'SYSTEM') INTO post_name FROM UAC_USER WHERE UPPER(TRIM(USER_ID)) = UPPER(TRIM(:NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_USER_ID));
                :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_USER_POST_NAME := post_name;
            END IF;

            IF INSERTING THEN
                :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_TYPE_CODE := 'I';
            ELSIF UPDATING THEN
                IF :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_TYPE_CODE <> 'D' OR :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_TYPE_CODE IS NULL THEN
                    :NEW.LAST_REC_TXN_TYPE_CODE := 'U';
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END;

I want to write a regex to match start from CREATE TABLE up to but not including "CREATE OR REPLACE...", once I see "CREATE OR REPLACE", then stop the matching and exclude "CREATE OR REPLACE" in the match.
the desired match is:
CREATE TABLE "abc01"."SLI_EDF_INSTR" 
       (    "EDF_INSTR_KEY" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EDF_KEY" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "INSTR_KEY" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "LAST_REC_TXN_USER_ID" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "LAST_REC_TXN_TYPE_CODE" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "LAST_REC_TXN_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "LAST_REC_TXN_USER_POST_NAME" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE);
    
             

How to do this?
In notepad++, I try to tick the checkbox ". matches newline", select "regular expression" then find
CREATE TABLE.+(?![CREATE OR REPLACE])

but it match all words.

This Regex will match anything Starting with CREATE, using negative lookahead to not match the OR REPLACE, picking up anything till the next semicolon.
CREATE(?! OR REPLACE)[\S\s]*?;

Update: An alternative and more efficient approach would be:
CREATE(?! OR REPLACE)[^;]*;

In Notepad++ use search and mark and the regex and see for yourself.


Result:

